# tf.train.import_meta_graph behaves differently from tf.train.Saver

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to setup a backup/restore mechanism in my deep learning code.
Unfortunately, I had trouble while trying to restore variables from a saver initialized with the metagraph only:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Create variable
v = tf.get_variable('v', shape=[3], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
# New node
inc_v = v.assign(v+1)
# Add an op to initialize the variables.
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
# Create saver
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    inc_v.op.run()
    # Save the variable
    save_path = saver.save(sess, "./ckpt/my_model")

# Now reload everything:
tf.reset_default_graph()

# Create variable.
v = tf.get_variable("v", shape=[3])
# create the saver for restoration, this one works
#saver = tf.train.Saver()
#This one doesn't work
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('{}.meta'.format(save_path))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # restore
    saver.restore(sess, save_path)
    # Check the values of the variables
    print('v : {}'.format(v.eval()))
```

The error resulting from the second solution is the following:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value v
     [[Node: _retval_v_0_0 = _Retval[T=DT_FLOAT, index=0, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](v)]]
```

Although the first one (saver = tf.train.Saver()) works perfectly fine.
Do you know why am I experiencing such behaviour, and how should I be using the import_meta_graph function ?

Thank you in advance for your help